# HTML5 video doesn't go fullscreen on iPad

Tags: ipad, html5-video, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I've set up a HTML5 video on my website [here](https://woodydesign.it/).

It works perfectly on every (tested) device, except iPad. Namely, the fullscreen button doesn't work and the video doesn't go fullscreen.

Any idea on the reason why?

Should I use webkitbeginfullscreen? Or use ontouchstart insted of click?

**JS:**

```
window.onload = function() {

// Video
var video = document.getElementById("video");

// Buttons
var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
var muteButton = document.getElementById("mute");
var fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");

// Sliders
var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
var volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");


[...]

// Event listener for the full-screen button
fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
    } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
    }
});


[...]

}
```